# How to use emberjs and internationalization

Tags: javascript, internationalization, ember.js

I am trying to understand how to internationalize a web-app developed with emberjs.

I found the [ember-i18n package](https://github.com/zendesk/ember-i18n) that I think is a good solution, but I can't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing you'll need to do is to create hash with all your localizations, you always pair up a identifier with the localized string.

The best practice here is to create a put all locales you have into a seperate file. (like loc-english.js)

```
Em.I18n.translations = {
  'login.loginbutton': 'Login',

};
```

When your webapp is getting loaded, make sure you load your strings file. All string must be loaded before you render the first view with ember.

The actual use is quite simple you just use the 't' helper in your template

```
<button class="login">{{t login.loginbutton}}</button>
```

Which will result in Login

You can find more information at: https://github.com/zendesk/ember-i18n/blob/master/README.md

Comment: This part works fine for me - it's figuring out which Em.I18n.translations object to use at runtime which I find confusing. Should the server be figuring this out and including the right locale file? If so, how does that fit with providing a single "build" js file? Do the different locales get different production build files?